# Code to Flowchart-Program for Mac OS?

Tags: development, drawing

I'm searching an alternative Program which can draw Flowcharts for pieces of sourcecode. I found Programs like "C/Delphi/Basic Code 2 Flowchart" or "Visustin" but they're only for Windows.

Helpful and lazy as it is - I'm searching for a program that turns C++ code into Flowcharts to have a better overview what my program does.

Answer (score 1):

Python Call Graph, a Python module that creates call graph visualizations for Python applications.
https://github.com/gak/pycallgraph

code2flow, turn your Python and Javascript code into DOT flowcharts
https://github.com/scottrogowski/code2flow

Comment: Thanks - found a code2flow-Version where you can put in your code online and get a flowchart...seems to work with c++-Code too. Not very precise but sufficient for overviews. http://www.code2flow.com/#

Answer (score -1):

OmniGraffle is the Gold Standard for flow charts!

Strom looks useable:
http://flowproject.economy-x-talk.com/file.php?node=download

But I don't think their is one specifically for adding a flowchart to source code other than OmniGraffle and you will need teh PRO version!

Depending on what code you are developing Xcode Core Data does have some tools to help you visualise the data flow.. Not sure if that is really teh same thing.

Comment: How would either of these tools generate flowcharts out of source code automatically (which seems to be what the OP is looking for)?

Comment: They don't . And in my answer I am assuming nothing!